# Issues with breakpoints in ts-node

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, ts-node

I faced a very strange problem. I have two working PC and one of them stop breaking on the breakpoints in one day. Another PC works properly the same as before.
I tried to reinstall `Node JS`, `ts-node` and then even hard reset for windows (I use Windows) but without any success.
Then I thought that probably issue in my project and I tried to clone  [hello world](https://github.com/RisingStack/node-typescript-starter) project from google tutorial and I found that I still can't debug with it!
So I successfully run an app on my port but breakpoint won't hit. This stop working in VS Code, in WebStorm and even Chrome debugger.

This is how I run an app: `"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" --inspect --require ts-node/register C:\Projects\node-typescript-starter-master\src\index.ts`

Then I opened dev tools from chrome and I see this:

[image]

Then I pressed "inspect" and I see message in console:
`Debugger attached. Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/8bae9408-867c-4278-9148-b6c90b35a8ae For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector Debugger attached.`

This is the next window. Seems like I missing any files overhere.

[image]

Does this mean that something is wrong with my file mapping ?
Please, let me any suggestion what can be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one of workaround is to don't use ts-node and just use default node js debugger config from WebStorm with adding TypeScript prelaunch compilation script.

Here is a screenshot how to configure:
[image]